# How to restrict mysqlimport usage?

Tags: mysql, security

I have a need in my PHP application (using Zend Framework for what it matters), to import a CSV file into a MySQL database.

I currently do this by using `shell_exec()` to run a `myysqlimport` command the imports the file successfully. To make this work, I had to add `set-variable=local-infile=1` into my `/etc/my.cnf`. I have also granted `File_priv` within MySQL to the user that I run the script as.

However, I understand this may not be secure. What is the correct way to allow `mysqlimport` to run securely, for only one user?

I'm using MySQL version 5.0.77 on a CentOS Linux server, with PHP 5.2.12.

Answer (score 1):

I recommand that you use "LOAD DATA INFILE" Sql Query instead of shell_exec with mysqlimport : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html